# Not able to display very large calculation value in editext

Tags: java, android, android-layout

```
private TextView info;
private EditText input;
private Button getInfo;
long answer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getInfo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    getInfo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            String s2 = input.getText().toString();
            long inputNumber = Integer.parseInt(s2);
            for (int i = 0; i <= inputNumber; i++) {

                answer = fibonacci(i);
            }
            input.setText(answer + "");
        }
    });
}
public static long fibonacci(long n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}
```

I made a program which generates fibonacci series for the number I give  input through edit text and display the output value in edittext .Issue is when I enter 30 it generates fibonacci series but when I enter 50 or 100 app does not respond and stops .

Comment: because you are doing the calculations on the main thread and therefor blocking the UI updates. Create an async task to do the wok then return the result.

Comment: why are you computing all fibonaccis for a given input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because you have a lot of calculation on UI thread.
Try calculate it in AssyncTask, for example.